# Prove by induction that $b(n)=b(n-1) + b(n-2) \space\text{for}\space n\geq3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

It is given that $b(1)=1 \space\text{and}\space b(n)=a(n+1)+a(n-1) \space\text{for}\space n\geq2$.

> Prove by induction that $b(n)=b(n-1) + b(n-2) \space\text{for}\space n\geq3.$

Here, $a(n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I did not really use Induction, I just use the definition of the sequence in terms of the Fibonacci numbers and in the end I show that it is also true for $n=3$ directly. 
$
\text{The fibonacci sequence is defined as:}\\
a(n+1)=a(n)+a(n-1)\quad \quad \\
\text{I have:}\\
b(n)=a(n+1)+a(n-1)\\
\Rightarrow b(n)=a(n)+a(n-1)+a(n-2)+a(n-3)\\
b(n)=[a(n)+a(n-2)]+[a(n-1)+a(n-3)]\\
\text{apply the definition of the sequence to get:}\\
b(n)=b(n-1)+b(n-2)\\
\text{now I just need to check that the statement is true for $n=3$}\\
b(1)=1\\
b(2)=a(3)+a(1)=3\\
b(3)=a(4)+a(2)=4\\
\Rightarrow b(3)=b(2)+b(1)$